# How to get more than 350 favorites with SoundCloud API?

Tags: soundcloud

I have about 600 likes on my soundcloud (my profile: https://soundcloud.com/bogem/likes) and I try to get full list of my likes.
But I can't get more than 300 favorites:

```
$ curl 'https://api.soundcloud.com/users/75306957/favorites?client_id=HIDDEN&limit=150&offset=300'
{"errors":[{"error_message":"403 - Forbidden"}]}
```

Even authorised:

```
$ curl 'https://api.soundcloud.com/me/favorites?client_id=HIDDEN&limit=150&oauth_token=HIDDEN&offset=300'
{"errors":[{"error_message":"403 - Forbidden"}]}
```

What do I do wrong or is there any limits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use the [linked_partitioning pagination method](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#pagination) which will return you a `collection` object that contains your likes, and a `next_href` that gives you the URL to paginate to.

There's [a blog post about dropping support for offset-based pagination](https://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/offset-pagination-deprecated).